# Illegal access exception : Eclipse Persistence Localization

Tags: java, jpa

I'm developing a web application using JPA and Spring MVC, and I get an annoying exception about Eclipse Persistence localization. Here is the stack trace :

```
mars 09, 2014 2:23:06 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader findResourceInternal
Infos: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org/eclipse/persistence/internal/localization/i18n/LoggingLocalizationResource_fr.properties.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
mars 09, 2014 2:23:06 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
Infos: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.eclipse.persistence.internal.localization.i18n.LoggingLocalizationResource_fr_FR.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2566)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1436)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1400)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1296)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:795)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.localization.EclipseLinkLocalization.buildMessage(EclipseLinkLocalization.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.localization.EclipseLinkLocalization.buildMessage(EclipseLinkLocalization.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.localization.LoggingLocalization.buildMessage(LoggingLocalization.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.logging.AbstractSessionLog.formatMessage(AbstractSessionLog.java:987)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.logging.DefaultSessionLog.log(DefaultSessionLog.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:3480)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4669)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4641)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4617)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4539)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.logout(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.logout(ServerSession.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.removeSessionFromGlobalSessionManager(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.undeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.close(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.finalize(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:344)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:101)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:32)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:190)
```

As I'm new to JPA and Spring MVC, I don't know what causes this exception. Why do I have this exception and how to solve it ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you get a solution for this issue?

Comment: @alsobubbly Unfortunately no, I just restarted my project from scratch :/ (it wasn't a big one, thankfully)

Answer (score 0):

I've setup my Eclipse WTP server to "Automatically publish after a build event". After each automatic publish I've encountered the same error messages as You have shown.

There are two ways to solve this issue.

- Turn your Eclipse Server Setting to "Never publish automatically".
- Add a Servlet Shutdown Hook, which does close the JPA's EntityManagerFactory explicitly.

You can add a shotdown hook easily to a ServletContextListener. In my case this is a GuiceServletContextListener, but it should be valid for any ServletContextListener.

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener;

@WebListener
public class BmjServletContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    Injector injector;

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        injector.getInstance(EntityManagerFactory.class).close(); // <--- POI !!
        super.contextDestroyed(servletContextEvent);
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        super.contextInitialized(servletContextEvent);
    }

    protected Injector getInjector() {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule1(), new MyModule2());
        return injector;
    }
}
```